# How to get JSONArray which has no JSONArray keyword in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-spinner

I am new to this JSON, I am trying to get the JSON values, it is actually as JSONArray with No name. I have gone through some tutorials where they accessed through JSONArray Keyword. But in my JSON File there is no such ArrayName. Kindly help me to solve this. This is my JSON Value:

```
 [
   {"id":"4","name":"Trichy"},
   {"id":"5","name":"Pondy"},
   {"id":"6","name":"Kovai"},
   {"id":"7","name":"Madurai"},
    {"id":"8","name":"Chennai"},
   {"id":"9","name":"Hyderabad"}
   ]
```

I need to get "name" from this. Here comes my MainActivity file.

```
        try {
            // Locate the NodeList name
            JSONArray json=new JSONArray(???); //I dont know what to give here 
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                Cites worldpop = new Cites();
                worldpop.setCity(jsonobject.optString("name"));

                cit.add(worldpop);

                // Populate spinner with country names
                worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("name"));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is my City.java file.

```
package com.example.user.spinnercontrol;


public class Cites {
private String city;

public String getCity()
{
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city)
{
    this.city=city;
}
}
```

This is my JSON.java file (for reference)

```
package com.example.user.spinnercontrol;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONCity {

public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    // Download JSON data from URL
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // Convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {

        jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
}
```

Comment: before the  [  ] any keyname is there???

Comment: No... There is no keyname for this JSON Array.

Comment: only that much json is there??? any other thing is not there apart from it??

Comment: Yes, that's my 1st JSON file. To list the city name in spinner and based on this selection, I will proceed further. But I stuck in this itself. I need to display these 6 city names in Spinner.

Comment: then use like this `JSONArray json=new JSONArray(response);`

Comment: Fine, but What is the "response" passed inside JSONArray ?

Comment: I implemented, but it shows Error. Please help me. Error is "Cannot resolve the symbol"

Comment: you are getting the whole json in string...this response is tht string

Comment: in whatever variable you are storing that output...

Comment: r you saving this file in assets folder??

Comment: Sorry about my last comment. Sent by mistake. I am saving in jSonArray. I have added json.java file for reference

Comment: `JSONArray json=new JSONArray(result);` try this

Comment: "result" is in my JSON.java fiile right? how can I use that I MainAcitvity.java. 

Same error- Cannot resolve the symbol

Comment: i update it in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MainActivity class should be like this ::

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
JSONObject jsonobject;
ArrayList<String> worldlist = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Cites> cit = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    JSONArray arr = JSONCity.getJSONfromURL("http://www.prateektechnosoft.com/justcall/cities/getall");

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

        try {
            jsonobject = arr.getJSONObject(i);

            Cites worldpop = new Cites();
            worldpop.setCity(jsonobject.optString("name"));

            cit.add(worldpop);

            // Populate spinner with country names
            worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("name"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

    // Spinner adapter
    mySpinner
            .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    worldlist));

    // Spinner on item click listener
    mySpinner
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                           View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });


}

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works fine. :)

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference

I am getting this error now.

Comment: you changed something?>

Comment: No. I didnt. I run the application after few mins and I also copied the MainActivity which you updated as answer and pasted it. Getting the same issue.